# Trouble with STM8S003F3 flashing

Tags: iar, stm8

Could STM32S003F3 be flashed with SWIM interface only (SWIM, RST, VCC, GND, bare IC without any other elements)? I'm trying to flash it with ST-LINK/V2 and last version of IAR (Kickstart) and debugger reports that:

```
Errors while setting configuration with MCU name STM8S003F3: gdi-error [40409]: No answer from the SWIM: check chip connections and power supply; try a power on reset
```

So i'm wondering where could be the trouble :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was obvious - STM32S003 can't work without capacitor at VCAP pin. So adding that capacitor will fix the problem.